# Is there a way to search html elements in google or any way to find out elements without passing the URL?

Tags: html, web-scraping, google-search

Is it possible to search a particular element using google?

or any way to find out elements without passing the URL?

### A broad search to find out elements.

**Ex**: I want to find if any of the websites has this class.

```
.main-category-box.category-5920.cf
```

---

[image: class_example.png]

Answer (score -1):

Maybe Scrapy for Python is your solution: https://scrapy.org/